# Get selected files in folder as pyinstaller exe argument from context menu

Tags: python-3.x, contextmenu, command-line-arguments

I have created an image to pdf merger. I want to make it accept selected files as argument. in regedit i have added it like  `@="Pdfmerger.exe %1"`. For two selected files it run twice. for three thrice and so on.

```
@="Pdfmerger.exe %*, @="cmd /c pdfmerger.bat % *" none worked

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\PDFMerger]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\PDFMerger\command]
@="d:\\pdfmerger.exe  %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PDFMerger]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PDFMerger\command]
@="d:\\pdfmerger.exe  %1"
```